# Set jQuery animation speed according to button value

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am struggling with jQuery and cannot seem to find any solution from web searching nor from experimenting myself.

I need to change the speed of an animation according to the value of a radio button, but my code doesn't work. I even tried to reload the page after checking a radio button then putting its value as the speed, but nothing.
I'm kind of lost.

Here's the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hER9V/) of what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a constant value 1400 as the duration... this essentially is the speed, as it is the amount of time it takes to get from start to finish.

EDIT:

Now that you are trying 'speed' as your duration, keep in mind that getting the value from the radial returns you a string.  You need to convert it to a number with parseInt(speed) before you can use it as the animation duration.

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hER9V/7/)

Comment: :/ i dont know what's happening. i set it to "speed" when i wrote it. but still it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Ah, in that case it's because speed is a string value, and the parameter is expecting a number.  Try using parseInt(speed) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your the value of `speed` is a string. I used `parseInt()` to change it to `int`

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    var speed = $("input:radio[name ='speed']:checked").val();
    $(this).animate({left: "+=300" }, parseInt(speed));
});
```

Comment: yeah, i wrote "speed" but i dont know why it's set to 1400